# how can I prevent the editor event in Kendo grid?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

When I click on the download link in the attached example, I want only the download event to be executed, but not the editor event.

Dojo Example: https://dojo.telerik.com/EcEDiGUB/27

HTML:

```
<div id="grid"></div>
```

JS:

```
var grid;
$(document).ready(function(){
grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { 
      field: "name",
    },
    { 
      field: "file",
      template: function(e){
       return '<div class="box">' + e.file + '</div>';
      },
      editor: function(e){
        alert("open media editor");
        return true;
      }
    }
  ],
  dataSource: {
   data: [
    { id: 1, name: "Jane Doe", file: "<div class='container'></div>" +
                                        "<div class='file k-icon k-i-file-pdf'></div>" +
                                        "<div class='download k-icon k-i-download'></div>" +
                                      "</div>" },
    { id: 2, name: "John Doe", file: "<div class='container'></div>" +
                                        "<div class='file k-icon k-i-file-pdf'></div>" +
                                        "<div class='download k-icon k-i-download'></div>" +
                                      "</div>" +
                                      "<div class='container'></div>" +
                                        "<div class='file k-icon k-i-file-xls'></div>" +
                                        "<div class='download k-icon k-i-download'></div>" +
                                      "</div>" }
   ],
   schema:{
    model: {
     id: "id",
     fields: {
       file: { type: "string"}
     }
    }
   }
  },
  editable: true,
}).data("grid");


$(".download").on("click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("download media"); 
});
```

It is now that the editable mode:

```
editable: true,
```

should be kept, because it is possible to edit as well as to start a download.

How can I start the download by clicking on the download icon without the editor event being fired?

Comment: do you want only first column to be editable or second too?

Comment: Only the first column must be editable

Comment: In another case all columns should be editable, is there a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the [`columns.editable`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.editable) property:

```
{ 
      field: "file",
      template: function(e){
       return '<div class="box">' + e.file + '</div>';
      },
      editable: function(){
        return false;
      },
      editor: function(e){
        alert("open media editor");
        return true;
      }
    }
```

[Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@bubblemaster/OjUSUrAS)